# How do I add characters to the beginning or end of result of paste0?

Tags: r, string-concatenation

I am trying to create a character string that looks something like 
`"c,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"`

I am able to get the number part of the string by doing:

```
paste0(1:200, collapse = ",")
```

How would I add "c," to the beginning of the result of `paste0`?  Alternatively, how could I join ",c" end of the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want the string c, not the function right?

```
paste0(c("c", 1:8), collapse = ",")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  This also worked for me:  `paste0("c,", paste0(1:200, collapse = ","))`, and for amending to end of string `paste0(paste0(1:200, collapse = ","), ",c")`

Answer (score 6):

We can wrap with `paste`

```
paste0("c(", paste0(1:200, collapse = ","), ")")
```

---

Or with `sprintf`

```
sprintf("c(%s)", paste0(1:200, collapse=","))
```

If we need only 'c', then use

```
sprintf("c,%s", paste0(1:200, collapse = ","))
```

Comment: Thanks.  This wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but your wrapping example helped me solve the issue I had with amending to the end of `paste0`

Answer (score 2):

Create a vector made up of `c` and `1:8` and then use `toString`:

```
toString(c("c", 1:8))
## [1] "c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"
```